# Android Linux system call List

Tags: android, system, kernel

Does anyone know where I can find the list of system call that can be used in Android Mobile phones? I guess that looking to the kernel should work, but I cannot find any *.h or *.c with the declaration of them.

Best regards

Answer (score 5):

You primarily want section 2 of the linux kernel manual pages.

Very little is unique to Android, the few gotchas being in the android docs (no sys-V IPC, AF_INET sockets won't work unless you are in the network group, etc).  Most of the android additions are drivers (Binder, etc) and novel usage patterns (for example of user IDs) rather than actual syscalls.

If you actually need the syscall numbers you can find them in bionic/libc/SYSCALLS.TXT within the sources

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the Bionic sources for the system call list. Since, Bionic is the C-Library, that Android works off.

Answer (score 0):

Try [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r45/libc/SYSCALLS.TXT)

It is located in `SYSCALLS.TXT` file inside of libc directory under certain Android version. Example above is system call on Android 11.